# Responsive fixed footer with clickable banner rotator?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to rotate some ad banners on a few of my webpages.  I cant find instructions online. I can find fixed footers but I want the banners to work on mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transform and animation properties to accomplish something like this. RotateZ defines a 3D rotation along the z-axis.

```css
.rotate {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: roll 1s infinite;
  transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}

@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="rotate">Banner Ad</h1>
```